# Displaying images as part of multiattribute labels using QGIS

Tags: qgis, labeling, image, html, expression

I would like to display images referenced in an attribute column as part of a multiattribute label, so that I can eventually print them with the map.  I do not want to display geotagged images, since this allows me not to move the photos manually and also not to show multiple attributes at once.

Is there a way to style labels (by expression or html) as to also show the corresponding images of the individual features?

Comment: There is some more-or-less recent discussion on html labels here: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/32098

Answer (score 1):

Use an additional symbol layer of type `Raster image marker` to show a picture. Use data driven override to define the path to the image (e.g. based on an attribute value that stores the image's path as text).

*Screenshot: each point has an image attached:*
[image]

If you want to move the pictures freely, copy/paste the initial points to a new layer and move these points. On this new layer, keep only the `Raster image marker` symbol layer and delete the `Single Symbol` points symbol layer.

*Moving the points on the copied layer with vertex moves the images (additonally with lines added with geometry generator):*
[image]

I also used data driven override for size and offset to handle orientation/rotation: different sizes and offset for landscape and portrait oriented pictures, based on their exif value, e.g. to size landscape pictures with 44, portrait with 32 (`"img_src"` is the attribute with the path of the image):

```
case
when map_get (exif ("img_src"), 'Exif.Image.Orientation')=8
then 32
else 44
end
```

Answer (score -1):

See here a tutorial by Totò Fiandaca: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kckrr6M3t4A

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The linked video just shows the result, but does not explain how to create image labels. You should update your answer to include this information.